# Lesser number of rows but higher size?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I have two different tables in redshift, let's say  **A** and **B**. Both the tables have 3 columns with the same data types.

While **B** has 3 times the number of rows as compared to **A**, **A** has a higher size compared to **B**. How is this possible?

Number of rows on A: 6,789,634,116

Number of rows on B: 18,191,553,916

Size of A: 491604 mbytes

Size of B: 423745 mbytes

[EDIT]

The table creation queries were as such:

```
CREATE TABLE A
(
   uid          varchar(128)   NOT NULL,
   client_id_1  integer        NOT NULL,
   client_id_2  integer        NOT NULL
);
```

and no different for TABLE B.

Comment: Things like indices can cause a table's size to vary.  Have you looked into this?

Comment: Both tables were created with the same settings, and are within the same schema as well.

Comment: Can you [try doing a vacuum](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_VACUUM_command.html) on both tables, and then compare the sizes afterwards?

Comment: Also, you might want to post the create table statements here (or maybe just one, if both really are the same).

Comment: Compression of varchars can also be a reason, but this looks more like table bloat (which a `vacuum full` should clean up)

Comment: I've been reading, and it says that `vacuum` may take a lot of time (and CPU if worse). I'm not the only one on redshift. Would it be okay?

Comment: Please do not tag Redshift questions with `postgresql`. Although they do share common roots, they are sufficiently different

Comment: Check the values of uid column. uid column values length can be more in table A in comparison to uid values of table b. Run a query something like select length(uid), count(*) from tableA group by length(uid) and perform same operation on tableB. You will get the idea if you have large number of values in table A which have more length.

Comment: may be compression related - please can you show the current compression for the columns on both tables, and then run analyse compression tablename on both and see what you get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Amazon Redshift,

> UPDATE=DELETE+INSERT.

Hence, you don't see those DELETED records when you do, SELECT count(*) from A.
But DELETED records are occupying space on Hard Drive, hence Size is more in Table A.

Do a vacuum on table A. You should see less size.

```
Vacuum A;
```

Refer Amazon Redshift documentation for more information.